# Find all unique n-combinations of n-arrays

Tags: arrays, unique, combinations

Assuming I have `n` arrays of the same length `m`.

How can I find all fully unique `n-combinations` of the elements of those arrays? Either language or pseudo code is totally fine.

Example with `n=2` and `m=2`:

```
arr1 = {a, b}
arr2 = {c, d}

returnUniqueCombinations();

//Should return
//a,c
//a,d
//b,c
//b,d
```

Comment: Please add your used program language

Comment: a combination (a, b) and (b, a) is the same or different?

Comment: A combination of (a,b) and (b,a) is the same.